# Dudas al tratar de gestionar WordPress mediante código PHP + themes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

¡Hola, muy buenas!

Veréis, ya tengo experiencia con WP pero no a nivel de programación y meterme en los temas o modificar plugins.

Estoy aprendiendo bastante estos días en cuanto a las acciones y los filtros que se hacen en wordpress, algo he visto sobre hooks (esto todavía tengo que mirarmelo mejor) y el caso es que me urge aprender a manejar a mi antojo WP pero a nivel más de backend y PHP.

**1.- Necesito optimizar webs a nivel de temas:** Necesito saber cómo deshabilitar las funciones que no esté usando en mi plantilla para agilizar el tiempo de carga de la web (no quiero que se llamen a funciones que no se utilizan), ¿hay alguna manera de conseguir esto?

**2-. Necesito optimizar webs en general:** De esto sé bastante pero a nivel de plugins, optimización de imagenes, carga asíncrona, implementar algún sistema de caché, minimizar archivos CSS y JS, eliminar archivos que no se utilian siguiendo un poco lo que te marca el PageSpeed de Google o web similar (aunque a veces, al menos, el pageSpeed, funciona un poquillo regular creo).

**3.- Modificar página o posts específicos:** Necesito saber cómo modificar las páginas y los posts que tengo en WP pero a nivel de código (HTML, CSS y PHP), entiendo que WP va llamando a funciones como el getTitle, getContent etc, okay, ¿pero existe alguna manera de ver las páginas que tengo en código? Me he recorrido los ficheros del tema pero no hay manera.

**4.-** En general, aprender todo lo necesario a nivel backend de WP para añadir funcionalidades al tema, etc.

Dicho todo esto, si podéis orientarme de alguna manera o recomendarme algún tipo de curso o algún tipo de ruta de aprendizaje os lo agradecería mucho. Por el momento me he comprado dos cursos de udemy por 10€ y 12€ con muy buenas valoraciones, más de 24h sobre desarrollo de temas y plugins y bueno, voy a empaparme de info.

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones por lo que puede terminar cerrada, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Aun asi, la información que pides deberias de verla en los cursos que estas tomando, te recomiendo el de Gilbertz Rodriguez, https://www.udemy.com/course/aprende-a-construir-temas-desde-cero-a-avanzado-de-wordpress/ es un tema complejo por lo que no se puede dar una respuesta completa

Comment: Ohh entiendo, no lo sabía. Bueno, tan solo buscaba respuesta al punto número 1 porque es que estoy desesperado y no sé dónde buscar información, me siento abrmado. Un saludo.